# not closing sap.m.popover on ESC

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to prevent my popover closing or doing anything on ESC click, is there any setting I can use or what would be the best way to program this using the beforeClose function.

Answer (score 0):

The Popover Element itself doesn't provide a way to cancel the event on `beforeClose` nor an API method to cancel the close event on ESC.

Add a `keydown` event listener to the Popover on `afterOpen` and cancel the event there:

```
var popoverid = '__popover25';
var popoverElement = sap.ui.getCore().byId(popoverid);
popoverElement.attachAfterOpen(function() {
    $("#"+popoverid).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
           return false;
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, was too early this morning and I couldn't get it working. Then I actually read your code and realised I had already attached the afterOpen using the XML view. This will be really useful as we have alot of popovers that need the user to agree to stuff or check things before closing. SAP should really add this option like how modal is.